# jquery regex .* not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, regex

Attemping to use jQuery to find a button on a page "id=btn.*ar" using .* returns no matches even though the button is clearly on the page. Is there something about .* in jquery being different from other Regex's? The buttons exact id is btnClear so its obvious that btn.*ar should match

    $("id=btn.*ar")

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: jQuery regexes are normal. Can we have some more code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should work:

```
$('button').filter(function() {
    return this.id.match(/^btn.*ar$/);
}).do_something();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ID for an element use that as your first choice.

```
$("#btnClear")
```

If you are using the attribute filters you can match with

id contains "tnCl":

```
$("input[id*='tnCl']")
```

id starts with "btn":

```
$("input[id^='btn']")
```

id ends with "Clear":

```
$("input[id$='Clear']")
```

You just need to find out which part of the id you want.

if you had a group of buttons with ids ['btn1', 'btn2', 'btn3'];

using the selector:

```
$("input[id^='btn']")
```

would grab all three of them.